# PostgreSQL and Django Query

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to make a (Django) query to my database using the following syntax:

```
Derp.objects.all()
```

I have a production database and a default (development) database. So obviously, by default, that query above will use the default database.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to select my other database. A coworker suggested the following:

```
Derp.objects.all(using="development")
```

But that returns a TypeError:

```
all() got an unexpected keyword argument 'using'
```

Can someone tell me what the proper syntax is? I can't seem to find what parameters the all() method will actually accept.

Comment: The syntax and wording look like you are using the Django ORM. If so it would be helpful to know what version.

Comment: @MarkLavin django.VERSION prints (1, 3, 0, 'final', 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly off:

```
Derp.objects.using('production').all()
```

Obviously, the 'production' key needs to match whatever you've labeled your DB in settings.py.

Comment: Also, the database type (PostgreSQL) itself should be irrelevant since you're connecting through ORM.